# Como renomear um branch local no Git?

Tags: git

Como eu faço para renomear meu branch local do Git?

Eu não quero renomear um branch remoto, eu quero uma forma simples de renomear meu branch local.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Para renomear um branch, você usa o seguinte comando:

```
git branch -m <nome antigo do branch> <nome novo do branch>
```

Answer (score 2):

Vi muita gente com problemas, utilizando os sinais <> para tentar renomear o branch...
Bom, pra simplificar, digamos que você tem um branch chamado NfseISSOnline, mas você se  depara com a situação de ter que alterar para NfseSJP, você não irá utilizar os sinhais <>, basta digitar:

```
git branch -m NfseISSOnline NfseSJP
```

Primeiro o branch a ser alterado e na sequência o nome do novo Branch.

Comment: Jakson, a sua resposta não acrescenta nada novo às resposta já feitas. Acho que seria mais interessante como um comentário na resposta escolhida.

Comment: Sabe noobice? Acabei de cometer uma sem querer hahaha
Desculpe, queria responder a pergunta e tirar uma dúvida, da qual também tive no início, fui jogado nesse barco do amor chamado git sem saber o que fazer inicialmente hehehehe

Comment: Sem problemas.. hahahaha